# Ошибка при инициализации URL

Tags: ios, swift, url

Пытаюсь воспроизвести аудио файл.

```
let url = URL.init(fileURLWithPath: Bundle.main.path(forResource: name, ofType: nil)!)
    do {
        player = try AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: url)
        player.play()
    } catch {
        print("error")
    }
```

Выдает ошибку:

```
Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value: file.  
/Users/hrayr/Desktop/Projects/Подводный бой/Подводный бой/Music/AudioPlayer.swift, line 15
2020-05-06 13:51:49.010761+0400 Подводный бой[947:28055] Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil 
while unwrapping an Optional value: file /Users/hrayr/Desktop/Projects/Подводный бой/. 
Подводный бой/Music/AudioPlayer.swift, line 15
```

Как исправить? Заранее спасибо

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проверьте правильность имени и типа ресурса. В ошибке же описано что получен nil при попытке unwrap.